# How to fully disable sort on table visual in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a table visual, where I am only displaying KPIs, so I wanted to fully disable the 'sort' option.

By "fully disabled" I mean that when the pbix is published, not even letting a user sort it by clicking it... (If the user clicks the column title, it should not sort).

(i am consuming from a ssas tabular, so I dont have a 'Data' view/panel, I only have 'Model' and 'Report')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no option to do this. The workaround is to create a blank button to place over the top of the column headers so users can't click the sort buttons. See https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/How-to-disable-sorting-in-Table-visual/m-p/1240901/highlight/true#M548820

[image: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/317042iE98E42EAD9408B8C/image-size/large?v=v2&px=999]